# Kotlin problems with Android data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying data binding on Android using Kotlin but experiencing some problems. My gradle files are listed below.

**Top level:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0-beta3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App level:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        resValue 'string', 'package_name', applicationId
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'app-release', ext: 'aar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.55.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle-kotlin:0.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.pushtorefresh.storio:sqlite:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.pushtorefresh.storio:content-resolver:1.8.0'

    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-2'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm using the following code to inflate my view.

```
val binding = FragmentTransferListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

But when I try to build the project I get this error.

```
Error:(7, 31) Unresolved reference: databinding
Error:(28, 9) Unresolved reference: FragmentTransferListBinding
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlinAfterJava'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I tried adding databinding-compiler to kapt as suggested in some other answers

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.1.0-beta3'
```

But then I get the following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.append(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/google/common/collect/FluentIterable;
```

Comment: You should definitely add `kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.1.0-beta3'`. Try to clean and rebuild the app after that.

Comment: @Michael Yes as I've mentioned above I've already tried adding that but I'm getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just mean it's necessary to have this line in the `build.gradle`.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep it but is there any solution to the NoSuchMethodError?

Answer (score 2):

you need

```
kapt 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.1.0'
```

before dagger's dependency description

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding `version = "2.0.0` in

`dataBinding {
        enabled = true
        version = "2.0.0"
    }`

like referred in this [issued](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/356#issuecomment-228015108/) by **ubarua123** and **AlokBansal8** solved the problem of `NoSuchMethodError`

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete .idea, .build folder and invalidate&restart Android Studio